# Problem with exporting with gimp

Tags: graphics, macos

I usually export images through gimp. This time, I was on my new OS X Mavericks, as I tried to change the name of the image which was "LOST", was not working. I observed the toolbox going to another tool as I typed the letters. I knew that I was pressing a shortcut but when I tried to press another letter like "y", the letter showed at the name of the image. How am I suppose to name the image when I export it?

Answer (score 1):

This is [known issue](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=710943) with Gimp and Mavericks. Current workaround is to turn off all keyboard shortcuts (Preferences/Interface/Remove All Keyboard Shortcuts).

Answer (score 0):

Command-tabbing from the exec in the dock to GIMP in the dock back to exec once each time I export seems to be a decent workaround for me.